# Firestore - batch.add is not a function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) for Firestore batch writes lists only `set()`, `update()` and `delete()` as permitted operations.

Is there no way to add an `add()` operation to the batch? I need a document to be created with an auto-generated id.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

```
// Create a ref with auto-generated ID
var newCityRef = db.collection('cities').doc();

// ...

// Add it in the batch
batch.set(newCityRef, { name: 'New York City' });

// Commit at the end
await batch.commit();
```

The `.doc()` method does not write anything to the network or disk, it just makes  a reference with an auto-generated ID you can use later.

Comment: It throws `TypeError: batch.doc is not a function` if I use the `.doc().set()` chain.

Comment: Yes don't call `batch.doc()`, as you can see I am calling `.doc()` on a collection reference **outside of the batch**.

Comment: You're right, it does work. I had no idea that the `.doc()` command actually generates a unique ID offline, i.e. without a server call, or at least without creating an empty object in my collection, which was the whole point of me wanting to include the `add()` command in the batch in the first place. Thank you! I will accept your answer.

Comment: you need to ref the "id" of the doc() in order for it to work. Like this: db.collection('cities').doc().id

Comment: you should call creat instead of set, because you expect it throws an error if id already exist

Comment: If you are using AngularFire, use `this.db.createId();` to create a new docId as `.doc()` does not work (see https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1974)

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias well, batch only supports set(), update(), or delete() operations

Comment: For Python, use `db.collection(...).document()` as `.doc()` does not work. (see https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/collection.html )

Comment: Do not forget `batch.commit()` in the end

Comment: will this create the collection 'cities' if it doesn't exist? if no how to create it?

Comment: Maybe I am late on this, but now (2022) you can get the auto generated id document reference by using `ref = doc(collection(Firestore, 'collectionName'))`. The third example of this [link](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) is the reference for it.
And yes, it does create a new collection if the provided collection does not exist.

Answer (score 11):

I'll offer an answer for Firebase 9 in which the syntax differs from Firebase 8.

For Firebase 9, the equivalent of `add()` is `addDoc()` as explained at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_6 .  It is for when you're not using [batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.writebatch) nor [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.transaction).  As per the original problem posted, there is no equivalent of `addDoc()` on [batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.writebatch) nor [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.transaction) on Firebase 9 either.

I found a way to achieve the equivalent of `addDoc()` for a batch on Firebase 9 by following the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859144/2848676 as follows:

```
        const batch = writeBatch(db);
        const docADocRef = doc(collection(db, "DocA"));
        batch.set(docADocRef, {
           fieldA: "This is field of an instance of DocA"
        });
        const docBDocRef = doc(collection(db, "DocB"));
        batch.set(docBDocRef, {
           docAID: docADocRef.id
        });
        batch.commit();
```

In this example, instances of DocA and DocB are created and DocB receives a pointers to the DocA instance.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, using AngularFire2, I had to use the batch.set() method, passing as first parameter the document reference with an ID previously created, and the reference attribute:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
...
private afs: AngularFirestore
...
batch.set(
    this.afs.collection('estados').doc(this.afs.createId()).ref,
    er.getData()
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs

> Behind the scenes, .add(...) and .doc().set(...) are completely equivalent, so you can use whichever is more convenient.

Perhaps this applies to batches as well?

Comment: No it doesn't you need to call .set() on a new doc.

Comment: I do not know if it was like that before, but now there is a new "creat" that it will throw an error if the document already exists, at least in the back end, at the front end is't not possible

Answer (score 2):

For **PHP** you can try :

```
$batch = $db->batch();
$newCityRef = $db->collection('cities')->newDocument();
$batch->set($newCityRef , [ 'name'=>'New York City' ]);
```

Comment: This method worked for me. Is this PHP though `{ name: 'New York City' }`?

Comment: Thanks @Gjaa, I've fixed it

Answer (score 1):

To create a document with auto-generated ID with firestore batch, you cannot use the addDoc(). You have to use batch.set() with a reference to the document to be created as below

```
    const db = getFirestore();
    // Create a transaction to update both the product stock value and add the new stock data
    const batch = writeBatch(db);
    const prodRef = doc(db, `products/${productId}`);
    const stockRef = doc(collection(db, `stocks`);
    // newDocId = stockRef.id;
    batch.set(stockRef, stock, {merge: true}); //create new document with autoId
    batch.update(prodRef, {available : increment(quantity), stock: increment(quantity)});
    batch.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the  reference to the collection in which you are going to add the batch data
We loop over the req.body using forEach and set the each data to be added in to the collection using the set method

We commit the data and save the data to the collection using the commit method and on success ,send a success response.

[cloud firestore](https://truetocode.com/batch-add-to-google-cloud-firestore-database-collection-node-js-and-express/)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have list of cities and you want to write them in batch.

```
 final CityList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cities')
 WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
 for(CityList city in cities) {
    final newShoppingItem = ShoppingList.doc();
    batch.set(newShoppingItem, {
  'name': city.name,
  'createdAt': DateTime
      .now()
      .millisecondsSinceEpoch
});
}
 batch.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sam Stern's answer is the correct way to do it, although if you are using **AngularFire**, `.doc()` cannot be used withouth a parameter to generate a new docId (see https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1974).

The **AngularFire** way of doing this would be:

```
// Create a ref with auto-generated ID
const id = this.db.createId();
const newCityRef= this.db.collection("cities").doc(id);

// ...

// Add it in the batch
batch.set(newCityRef, { name: 'New York City' });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and it is mentioned in the docs for PHP

```
 $batch = $db->batch();

# Set the data for NYC
$nycRef = $db->collection('samples/php/cities')->document('NYC');
$batch->set($nycRef, [
    'name' => 'New York City'
]);

# Update the population for SF
$sfRef = $db->collection('samples/php/cities')->document('SF');
$batch->update($sfRef, [
    ['path' => 'population', 'value' => 1000000]
]);

# Delete LA
$laRef = $db->collection('samples/php/cities')->document('LA');
$batch->delete($laRef);

# Commit the batch
$batch->commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase 10, below works for me. My issue was to get a Firestore ID so that I could "set" the batch on it:

```
const db = getFirestore()
const batch = writeBatch(db)
// get a new id before the doc is created
const id = doc(collection(db, 'myCollection')).id
const docRef = doc(collectionRef, id)
batch.set(docRef, {some: 'doc')
batch.commit()
```