# Can I get the generated ID for a document created with batch().set using Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way that I can get the auto-generated ID for a document created as part of a batch using Firestore?

When using `.add()` I can easily get an ID:

```
db.collection('posts')
  .add({title: 'Hello World'})
  .then(function(docRef) {
    console.log('The auto-generated ID is', docRef.id)
    postKey = docRef.id
});
```

Using `.batch()` I can add a document with `.doc()` and `.set()`:

```
const batch = db.batch();

const postsRef = db.collection('posts').doc(postKey);
batch.set(postsRef, {title: 'Hello Again, World'});

const votesRef = db.collection('posts').doc(postKey)
                   .collection('votes').doc();
batch.set(votesRef, {upvote: true})

batch.commit().then(function() {
});
```

Can I get the auto-generated ID of the document that was added to `votes`?

**Update:**

Doug Stevenson is correct - I can access the ID at `votesRef.id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore - batch.add is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725357/firestore-batch-add-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Yes. You must instantiate your `ref` on each action. In other words, if you are iterating over an object or array, you must call `doc()` on each iteration.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you call [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) without any arguments, it will immediately return a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) that has a unique id, without writing anything to the database - the id is generated on the client.  So if you want that id, simply use the id property on that DocumentReference.  That id will become visible in the database after you've written that document.

Comment: I'm following the Firestore web documentation example: `var newCityRef = this.afs.collection("cities").doc();` gives me an error "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0". This is completely stopping me from moving forward at all.

Comment: @FiringBlanks Maybe angular does something different than the standard javascript api?

Comment: @DougStevenson It looks like they made it a required parameter. See here for more info: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/d43d461aaa2496d4cd12fd593373f6dad214716f/packages/firestore/src/api/database.ts#L397-L408

Comment: @Edric You're looking at doc() on the Firestore class.  I'm referring to doc() on CollectionReference.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/d43d461aaa2496d4cd12fd593373f6dad214716f/packages/firestore/src/api/database.ts#L1660

Comment: Maybe I am late on this, but now (2022) you can get the reference by using `ref = doc(collection(Firestore, 'collectionName'))`. The third example of this [link](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) is the reference for it.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue, And I thing there were changes at the API of firestore.

I was getting an error for code like :

```
const postsRef = db.collection('posts').doc(postKey);
batch.set(postsRef, {title: 'Hello Again, World'});
```

The change I found that was necessary is to take the `ref` of the doc object:

```
const postsRef = db.collection('posts').doc(postKey).ref;
```

I hope this helps you all !

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate the uid automatically beforehand the creation of document, you can make use of createID() function from angularFireAuth as follows:

`

```
constructor(
    private angularFireStore: AngularFirestore,
   ) {}

 const batch = this.angularFireStore.firestore.batch();

 const autogenUid = this.angularFireStore.createId();
 const collectionReference = this.angularFireStore.collection
                            ('collection_name').doc(autogenUid).ref;

 const docData = {first_field:'value', second_field:'value2'};
 batch.set(collectionReference, docData);
```

Comment: thanks for `createId` method reference from Angular Firestore. I remove a reference of `uuid` npm library now. Thanks again :pray: