# Genrate doc id in firestore v9 before the doc is created

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore v8 (web sdk) I was doing it like below:

```
firestore.ref().collection("genId").doc().id
```

But I can't figure out the correct syntax for v9 as `collection` doesn't have `doc()` method anymore.

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the Firebase documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_7):

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call `doc()`:
>
> ```
> import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
>
> // Add a new document with a generated id
> const newCityRef = doc(collection(db, "cities"));
>
> // later...
> await setDoc(newCityRef, data);
> ```

Instead of writing to the ref as the sample does, you can also get the ID from the document ref with:

```
console.log(newCityRef.id);
```

Comment: ahh this is nice!!

Answer (score 2):

You can call `collection` to get a `CollectionReference` Object and use this to call `doc`.

Collection: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#collection

Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#doc_2

```js
const ref = collection(firestore, "genId")
const id = doc(collection)
```

As per the API reference:

> If no path is specified, an automatically-generated unique ID will be
> used for the returned DocumentReference.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Seems like it would be doc(collection).id though as doc() returns docReference as far as I can see now.