# What is the equivalent of CollectionReference.doc() for version 9 of the Firebase JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to [add a new document in a firestore transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55677964) with version 9 of the Firebase JS SDK. In version 8, we can use

```
const newDocRef = db.collection('coll').doc();
```

to get a DocumentReference to a document that does not exist yet, and then do a

```
transaction.set(newDocRef, { ... });
```

to set the document in a transaction.
How would we do the same in version 9? The new [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) class does not seem have a `doc()` method as in [version 8](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc).
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Genrate doc id in firestore v9 before the doc is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859073/genrate-doc-id-in-firestore-v9-before-the-doc-is-created)

Answer (score 0):

There's a function `doc()` to create a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) and then `runTransaction()` to run a transaction. Try refactoring the code like this:

```
import { getFirestore, doc, runTransaction } from "firebase/firestore"

const newDocRef = doc(db, "col_name", "doc_id");

await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
  // ...
  transaction.set(newDocRef, { ...data });
});
```

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) has examples with both the name-spaced and functional syntax. Also checkout this answer for better explanation of syntax differences in V8 and V9:

[Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9/68987445#68987445)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to specify my own "doc_id". If it is outside of a transaction, I would use  [addDoc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#adddoc), but I need to do this in a transaction.

Comment: @Ping can you try `const newDocRef = doc(db, "col_name")` without doc ID?

Comment: Then I get `FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859140/10568623). This works for me:

```
const newDocRef = doc(collection(db, "coll"));

transaction.set(newDocRef, { ... });
```