# How do you add multiple documents at once to a collection in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am somewhat new to Firebase and looking for the ability to write multiple JSON objects into a collection under random IDs in one operation. I am just using firestore and auth(not shown) along with react.

So far I have

```
Function TestDocs () {
    {addDoc(collection(db, 'randomData'),  {**object 1 example data**},{**object 2 more example data**}
   )
}
```

I have a button on a webpage which adds the data into the DB. When I check Firestore only the first object is loaded and not the second... on top of this, assuming that I wanted to add hundreds of objects(not just 2), how would I go about this?

I was looking through the documentation for Firestore batch writes but it only lists set(), update() and delete() as permitted operations so I am not sure how it would work. Thanks in advance

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do this in two steps:

1. Create a reference to a new document with a new unique ID:

   ```
   // Generate two new document references with a generated ids
   const newRef1 = doc(collection(db, "randomData"));
   const newRef2 = doc(collection(db, "randomData"));
   ```
2. Write to that reference in your [batch or transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

Also see:

- [Firestore - batch.add is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725357/firestore-batch-add-is-not-a-function) (which contains the older namespaced syntax for doing the same).
- The last snippet in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), which shows this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do this without using Firebases batch function. Each transaction or batch of writes can write to a maximum of 500 documents. I was looking to update my app with more than 500 and found a video on YouTube showing another way to do this.

I had to tweak the script a bit to get what I needed but the idea is there.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qg2_VFFcAI8

Comment: Consider adding what you had to tweak to your answer. Use the edit feature (button bottom left of your answer)