# Can I add multiple documents together in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can I insert multiple objects at once in firestore? in mongoDB `db.collection.insert` we can insert an array of objects. Is it possible in firestore?

Comment: Your question is saying two different things.  The question title is asking if you can add multiple *documents* together, and the question body is asking about adding multiple *objects* at the same time.  They are not the same thing - are you talking about documents or object fields within documents?

Comment: @DougStevenson - documents in a collection. Adding array of documents like 
 mongoDB is that possible? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618601/how-to-create-update-multiple-documents-at-once-in-firestore

Comment: I found that answer simply by putting your question into a Google search. It was the first hit.

Comment: It's saying about single batch, what I 'm asking here is something like `db.collection('users').add([user1, user2, user3, user4]);` is possible or not?

Comment: A batch *is* multiple documents at the same time, which is what your question is asking.  If that's not what you want, what specifically are you trying to accomplish? What is the end result of the database, after everything is done?

Comment: I have an array of users, I want to add it together, don't want to insert one at a time.

Comment: Then pass an object that describes the entire set of data you want to insert into the single document.  If you're still confused, you should ask a new question and fully describe what data you need to add, and what the final document should look like.